# Getting a group of CGI-Files to Execute in Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, perl, apache, ubuntu, cgi

Hi I have had an incredibly rough time trying to run three cgi-files for a website that i am working on. After reading up a ton, I have honestly found no solution and have tried many recommended solutions. I am on Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed Apache2. Right now I am following these instructions [Configure Apache](http://www.fiz-ix.com/2012/12/configure-apache-mysql-and-cgi-bin-on-an-ubuntu-lamp-server/)

I go thru all the steps and everything works fine, but I get to this step `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/fiz-ix` and it returns this in the terminal. 
`cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/apache2/sites-available/default’: No such file or directory`

I then put the files inside sites-available into a folder in sites-available that i made called default and it sitll didn't work though.

I really need some help. I have invested hours trying to get this to work and I really need to get apache to run CGI-Files soon.

Thanks

Comment: food for thought (maybe you'll have better luck over there) I've read someone type this type of question belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error with cgi and ubuntu 13.10 the following worked

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled 
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/cgi.load .
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/cgid.load .
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Regards,
Olav

Comment: thanks alot actually because now im one step closer! I get an internal server error. I used to get nothing haha,